# How to list products from equal subcategories but different parents?

Tags: magento-1.7, category

I have the following category tree:

- Men

  - Shoes
  - Accessories
- Women

  - Shoes
  - Accessories

And I need to list all shoes available (Men and Women) in a single page (mystore.com/shoes)

Any plugin/code/trick to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I wonder if tags could be any help here... In such a case, wouldn't it be better to have a Shoes and an Accessories category, and a tag for Men's, and another tag for Women's items? I'm not sure about how intuitive (not to mention if feasible at all) that would be though...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to list all shoes available (Men and Women) in a single page and your store URL look like (mystore.com/shoes), Then you need to create a parent shoes category and assign all the shoes product in this category. you can easily do this by admin panel.

Comment: Exactly agree, just as we would have suggested, no need to make it more complex than it already is.

Answer (score 0):

Check this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498556/magento-1-7-filter-products-by-multiple-categories. It describes how to get products from multiple categories. In order to display them on a particular page you will need to add custom controller or to add block to existing layout handle.